# Revoke user permission in perforce

Tags: perforce

P4 protects command returns user's permissions like below for instance.

```
p4 protects

read group user_group * //PROJECT1/...
list group user_group * //CENTER/USA/Connect/...,*
write user daniel.richter  * //APPS/Auto/Source/CENTER/China/Areos.csv
write user daniel.richter  * //APPS/Auto//Source/CENTER/China/NFE/CoreAs.csv
write group CENTER_CHINA_HP_NW_WRITE * //CENTER/China/HP_NW/ENGINE_SUB/...
list group user_group * -//POST/3G/...
list group user_group * -//PROJ/2005/DevTools/...
list group user_group * -//PROJ/STACK/Flow/...
list group user_group * -//GROUP1/OMR/EXAMPLE/...
list group user_group * -//APPS/Protect/APPS/...
list group user_group * -//APPS/Protect/Group/Apps.txt
```

With the above output, it is possible to remove/revoke the permission to an user in perforce using p4 command? Manually editing protection table is time consuming process, as i need to revoke the permission for multiple users. So, I need help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've set up your permissions to use groups (except for the special case of `daniel.richter`), you probably just want to remove that user from the groups `user_group` and/or `CENTER_CHINA_HP_NW_WRITE` rather than adding specific exclusions per user to the protection table itself.  You can run:

```
p4 groups USERNAME
```

to see what group(s) the user is part of, and then:

```
p4 group GROUPNAME
```

to edit the group(s).

Both of the above commands can be automated pretty easily in any scripting language.  A simple script to remove a user from all groups using P4Python might look like:

```
from P4 import P4
import sys

user = sys.argv[1]

p4 = P4()
with p4.connect():
    for line in p4.run_groups(user):
        group = p4.fetch_group(line['group'])
        group['Users'].remove(user)
        p4.save_group(group)
```

```
C:\Perforce\test\python>p4 groups bob
mygroup

C:\Perforce\test\python>python remove_from_groups.py bob

C:\Perforce\test\python>p4 groups bob

C:\Perforce\test\python>
```

Comment: I don't have a Unix env handy, but I bashed together a quick Python script.  The basic strategy in any language is the same, except if you're doing it as a pure shell thing you need to use `sed` to filter the username out of the plaintext form rather than being able to pop it out of a nice data structure.

Comment: it'd be something like `p4 groups USER | xargs -i p4 group -o {} | sed -s "s/USER$//" | p4 group -i` -- I'm not sure if you need to throw quotes around some parts of that to have xargs run the whole thing including the pipe, or if there's some other bit of plumbing needed to have each line of `p4 groups` output result in one `p4 group -o | sed | p4 group -i` invocation.  That'd be the general idea though.

Comment: We use p4 & P4V on both Windows and Ubuntu(Linux). So the following`remove_from_groups.py` script is working to remove a user from all groups. Further i will check to remove a user from particular/specified groups.

Comment: A good use for a script like this would be as a trigger on user deletion -- that way you can delete the user from P4V (or anywhere) and the server will automatically remove it from groups.  If you're invoking it manually I'm not sure it saves you that much time over just editing the group spec normally.

Comment: Actually we have multiple users and they are part of multiple groups, Hence looking script method to remove the users from certain groups.